# SharePoint Survey. Tally multiple checkbox responses

Tags: survey-list, multiple-values

I have a question in a survey where a user may select as many options as they like, for example they might select Excel, Word and Powerpoint or just Word.

When a user selects more than one choice it adds another option on to the results page as if their combination is a new option. What I would like is for each option to tally up the number of times someone has selected it.

Is this possible?

EDIT: I realise my description is not clear, so I have included a screen shot to show what I mean.

[image: Screen shots of my results page.]

Comment: Did you find a way to fix ur problem? I am facing a similar issue. Any help would great..
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a solution just a workaround: create a yes/no question for each selectable option so you can count 'yes' answers on those at the results page.